# a last touch event does not come if the view goes out of the screen programmatically

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, touch

I have a situation where I apply an effect to a UIView when a touch begins and reverse that effect when that touch ends. So basically I am tracking `touchesbegan`, `touchesEnded` and `touchesCancelled` methods of UIView. 
But the problem is that when the view goes out of the screen, i.e. when it or one of its parents gets removed from superview, it does not get any more touch events. Is there any way to give this "last" `touchesended` event to the view? Maybe if the UIView gets notified about being invisible, I can also use this event for that purpose.

Ok I am going to move the answers in comments to original question to make a good summary of important points.

- The reason I am tracking touch events is that I want to apply some
  nice effects such as glowing on touch start and remove those effects
  on touch ending.
- The reason why I can not simulate `touchesEnded` on removing those
  views is that I do not directly remove them. Instead I remove one of
  the ancestor views of them. I can not keep track of ancestor views
  all the way to UIWindow, it is technically impossible I think.
  Instead, framework should provide this to as an event I think.

Comment: just set the view.alpha = 0  instead of remove it ,or remove its parent, when touchesended, remove it

Comment: So, in your application the views are removed from the screen *while* you are interacting with them? It makes sense that if they are removed from the screen they no longer receive touch events...

Comment: Think of it in that way. You have two tabs and some views inside tabs. Then you tap on a view inside one tab. While your finger is still on that view, you change the tab with another finger of yours and you lose the touch on the view. But the problem is that touchesEnded or touchesCancelled method is not called when you lose the touch in that way.

Comment: If you want to keep that aproach you can simply simulate that last touch wherever you are making your view dissapear, for example on the view dissapearing part check a boolean to see if touch started was on that screen and if it was call your touches ended method.

Comment: The problem is that the views we are talking about may be deep inside the view hierarcy. So I am not directly removing them but instead I am removing one of the ancestor views of them. I can not have specific references to them in the places because they are general views and used in many places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by overriding `-(void)willMoveToWindow:(UIWindow *)newWindow` method and checking if `newWindow` is `nil`.